# Solving $\sqrt{x^2+1}=y+2\sqrt2$ , $9y^2(x+3y)=1-x^3y^3\qquad x,y=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $\begin{cases}\sqrt{x^2+1}=y+2\sqrt2\\
> 9y^2(x+3y)=1-x^3y^3\end{cases}$
>
> $x, y=?$

Here is what I've done:

From the second equation we have $$1+(-xy)^3+(-3y)^3=3.(-xy)(-3y)$$ $$1-xy-3y=0$$
$$y(x+3)=1 \quad\Rightarrow x=\frac1y-3$$
After plugging it in the first equation gives $$\sqrt{\frac1{y^2}-\frac6y+10}=y+2\sqrt2$$
$$y^4+4\sqrt2y^3-2y^2+6y-1=0$$
But I don't know how to sole this. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E4%2B4%5Csqrt2%20x%5E3-2x%5E2%2B6x-1%3D0) says it has two roots but I can't solve it by hand.

Comment: how did you get $1-xy - 3y = 0$?

Comment: @sku  $$A^3+B^3+C^3=3ABC \Rightarrow A+B+C=0$$ It comes from [this identity](http://www.prep4paper.com/Free-Printable-Worksheets/free-basic-math-worksheets/a-cube-plus-b-cube-plus-c-cube-minus-3abc-formula-proof.html#:~:text=a3%20%2B%20b3%20%2B%20c,%2D%20ab%20%2D%20bc%20%2D%20ca)